# How do I mount an external disk in qemu-system-ppc?

Tags: emulation, qemu

I am trying to use an external disk instead of a .img file in qemu-system-ppc. I am using the following code:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"

./qemu-system-ppc -L pc-bios -boot d -M mac99 -m 512 \
-prom-env 'auto-boot?=true' -prom-env 'boot-args=-v' -prom-env 'vga-ndrv?=true' \
-drive file=MacOS9.2.2.iso,format=raw,media=cdrom \
-drive file=/dev/disk3s2,format=raw,if=virtio \
-netdev user,id=network01 -device sungem,netdev=network01 \
-device VGA,edid=on \
```

When I run this code I get the following output from the terminal:

```
hamishmoore@Hamishs-Mini ~ % /Applications/QEMU\ Mac\ OS\ 9.2.2/qemu.command ; exit;
qemu-system-ppc: -drive file=/dev/disk3s2,format=raw,if=virtio: If device /dev/disk3s2 is mounted on the desktop, unmount it first before using it in QEMU
qemu-system-ppc: -drive file=/dev/disk3s2,format=raw,if=virtio: Command to unmount device: diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk3s2
qemu-system-ppc: -drive file=/dev/disk3s2,format=raw,if=virtio: Command to mount device: diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk3s2
qemu-system-ppc: -drive file=/dev/disk3s2,format=raw,if=virtio: Could not open '/dev/disk3s2': Permission denied

[Process completed]
```

The disk has been unmounted from the desktop. And I've tried formatting the disk a few different ways. I am running macOS Catalina.

Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

QEMU will print the suggestion about unmounting from the desktop for pretty much any error attempting to open a device as an image file. The important line here is the last one, which tells you the specific error:

```
qemu-system-ppc: -drive file=/dev/disk3s2,format=raw,if=virtio: Could not open '/dev/disk3s2': Permission denied
```

"Permission denied" usually means that the user you're running QEMU as does not have write access to the /dev/disk3s2 device; check the permissions/ownership on it.